# Newbie trying to rig eyes

Tags: rigging

I downloaded an unrigged .gltf cartoon model. Im going through youtube tutorials and every single one says to select "one" eye before you center the cursor to active. My problem is that I cant just select one eye. Both are selected when i click on one. I tried "separate selection" in edit mode but not sure if that worked. Both eyes are still selected, it went from mesh to just both eyes being highlighted although another "eye" entry has now showed up in the scene collection. Bean_eye.001. I still seemingly cant select just one eye by clicking on it. What am I doing wrong?[image]

model file:
https://we.tl/t-WkNRVWM9TX

Comment: Separate the mesh should work, maybe share your file

Comment: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmRHmQtSw3zfwphxk3BT5VZogSX9AuqfhQ2Aeuqv2X6jJv?filename=test.glb

Comment: the link doesn't work, could you please use another platform?

Comment: I'm guessing that your mesh object uses the mirror modifier?  If so, you can *Apply* the modifier, allowing you to select only what you need.  Of course, there may be other consequences or side-effects besides increasing the amount of vertices stored.  https://youtu.be/QB_eSNvOz6U

Comment: https://we.tl/t-WkNRVWM9TX new link

Comment: it works, select the eyes, switch to Edit mode, alt Z for transparency, select one of the 2 eyes, press P to separate as new object, back to Object mode (also maybe elect the eyes and right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry)

Comment: Thank you! The first part worked! This is great

Comment: There are also thousands of duplicate vertices on the eyes and on the body. Select each object in turn, go into Edit mode, Hit A to select All, then hit M > Merge by Distance. For the two eyes you'll briefly see a message in the middle of the bottom status bar saying that around 1700 vertices have been removed, and for the main body over 10,000 will be removed. This will be necessary if you then try to rig your model.

Comment: Done John, Thankyou!

Comment: I know Im not figuring this stuff out for myself even after a ton of attempts, but Im enjoying these little victories. Thank you peeps!

Answer (score 1):

Select the eyes, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for transparency, select one of the 2 eyes, press <kbd>P</kbd> to separate as new object, back to *Object* mode (also maybe elect the eyes and right click > *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry*).